# Saving stream object returned by webrequest

Tags: c#

I have a code to retrieve an XML file from the site, so I do as follows:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
       if (responseStream != null)
        {
            reportXML = XDocument.Load(responseStream.ToString());
        }
    }
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Retrieved.xml"))
    {
        reportXML.Save(writer);
    }
 }
```

But I debugged the app and it seems I lose everything on this line of code, so I have nothing anymore to save.

```
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
```

Any idea why it could be?

If I investigate the object I see this:

> Length = 'responseStream.Length' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NotSupportedException'

And the error is following:

> Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Proto\App\bin\Debug\System.Net.ConnectStream'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
reportXML = XDocument.Load(responseStream.ToString());
```

Calling `ToString()` on a stream like that is pretty much *never* going to give you anything useful. If you just want to load the *contents* of the stream, get rid of the `ToString` call:

```
reportXML = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
```

Alternatively, if you *really* just want to save it to disk, simply use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) and don't bother parsing it as XML in the first place.

Comment: wau nice, but XDocument.Load doesnt have stream as argument, how can i fix it?

Comment: @Alnedru: Yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx - what platform are you using? Perhaps you can use `XmlReader.Create(Stream)` and pass that in instead?